# ANTLR Source to Output

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer

I'm trying to implement something like a [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) feature for JavaScript as an assignment for one of my courses.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find a way to **output the source file directly to the console** without modifying the entire grammar.

Does anybody knows a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function DoClear(num, arr, text){ 
  Contract.Requires<RangeError>(num > 0); 
  Contract.Requires(num < 1000); 
  Contract.Requires<TypeError>(arr instanceOf Array); 
  Contract.Requires<RangeError>(arr.length > 0 && arr.length <= 9); 
  Contract.Requires<ReferenceError>(text != null); 
  Contract.Ensures<RangeError>(text.length === 0); 

  // method body
  [...] 

  return text; 
}  

function DoClear(num, arr, text){ 
   if (!(num > 0)) 
     throw RangeError; 
   if (!(num < 1000)) 
     throw Error; 
   if (!(arr instanceOf Array)) 
     throw TypeError; 
   if (!(arr.length > 0 && arr.length <= 9)) 
     throw RangeError; 
   if (!(text != null)) 
     throw ReferenceError 

   // method body
   [...] 

   if (!(text.length === 0)) 
     throw RangeError 
   else 
     return text; 
}
```

Comment: @sarnold, the principle might be applicable, but the link you posted is of ANTLR v2: its syntax greatly differs from today's ANTLR version, so it's most likely not going to help the OP (unless s/he is using v2... :)).

Comment: What's your grammar and calling programming currently look like?

Comment: @Bart, thanks for the catch; the URL looked so clean I completely missed the `2` in the domain.

Comment: @sarnold thanks for your help, but as Bart said, i'm using v3. Should've mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MateusBR, I should have paid more attention to the URL I found -- I assumed it _was_ v3. :) My mistake. hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few (minor) things you'll want to consider:

- ignore string literals that might contain your special contract-syntax;
- ignore multi- and single line comments that might contain your special `Contract` syntax;
- ignore code like this: `var Requires = "Contract.Requires<RangeError>";` (i.e. regular JavaScript code that "looks like" your contract-syntax);

It's pretty straight forward to take the points above into account and also simply create single tokens for an entire contract-line. You'll be making your life hard when tokenizing the following into 4 different tokens `Contract.Requires<RangeError>(num > 0)`:

- `Contract`
- `Requires`
- `<RangeError>`
- `(num > 0)`

So it's easiest to create a single token from it, and at the parsing phase, split the token on `"."`, `"<"` or `">"` with a maximum of 4 tokens (leaving expressions containing `"."`, `"<"` or `">"` as they are).

A quick demo of what I described above might look like this:

```java
grammar CCJS;

parse
  :  atom+ EOF
  ;

atom
  :  code_contract
  |  (Comment | String | Any) {System.out.print($text);}
  ;

code_contract
  :  Contract 
     {
       String[] tokens = $text.split("[.<>]", 4);
       System.out.print("if (!" + tokens[3] + ") throw " + tokens[2]);
     }
  ;

Contract
@init{
  boolean hasType = false;
}
@after{
  if(!hasType) {
    // inject a generic Error if this contract has no type
    setText(getText().replaceFirst("\\(", "<Error>("));
  }
}
  :  'Contract.' ('Requires' | 'Ensures') ('<' ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ '>' {hasType=true;})? '(' ~';'+
  ;

Comment
  :  '//' ~('\r' | '\n')*
  |  '/*' .* '*/'
  ;

String
  :  '"' (~('\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' . )* '"'
  ;

Any
  :  .
  ;
```

which you can test with the following class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = 
        "/*                                                                  \n" +
        "   Contract.Requires to be ignored                                  \n" +
        "*/                                                                  \n" +
        "function DoClear(num, arr, text){                                   \n" +
        "  Contract.Requires<RangeError>(num > 0);                           \n" +
        "  Contract.Requires(num < 1000);                                    \n" +
        "  Contract.Requires<TypeError>(arr instanceOf Array);               \n" +
        "  Contract.Requires<RangeError>(arr.length > 0 && arr.length <= 9); \n" +
        "  Contract.Requires<ReferenceError>(text != null);                  \n" +
        "  Contract.Ensures<RangeError>(text.length === 0);                  \n" +
        "                                                                    \n" +
        "  // method body                                                    \n" +
        "  // and ignore single line comments, Contract.Ensures              \n" +
        "  var s = \"Contract.Requires\"; // also ignore strings             \n" +
        "                                                                    \n" +
        "  return text;                                                      \n" +
        "}                                                                   \n";

    CCJSLexer lexer = new CCJSLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    CCJSParser parser = new CCJSParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

If you run the `Main` class above, the following will be printed to the console:

```
/*
   Contract.Requires to be ignored
*/
function DoClear(num, arr, text){
  if (!(num > 0)) throw RangeError;
  if (!(num < 1000)) throw Error;
  if (!(arr instanceOf Array)) throw TypeError;
  if (!(arr.length > 0 && arr.length <= 9)) throw RangeError;
  if (!(text != null)) throw ReferenceError;
  if (!(text.length === 0)) throw RangeError;

  // method body
  // and ignore single line comments, Contract.Ensures
  var s = "Contract.Requires"; // also ignore strings

  return text;
}
```

### BUT ...

... I realize that it isn't what you're exactly looking for: the `RangeError` is *not* placed at the end of your function. And that's going to be tough one: a function might have multiple `return`s, and is likely to have multiple code blocks `{ ... }` making it difficult to know where the `}` is that ends the `function`. So you don't know where exactly to inject this `RangeError`-check. At least, not with a naive approach as I demonstrated.

The only reliable way to implement such a thing is to get a decent JavaScript grammar, add your own contract-rules to it, rewrite the AST the parser produces, and finally emit the new AST in a friendly-formatted way: not a trivial task, to say the least!

There are various ECMA/JS grammars on the [ANTLR Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list), but tread with care: they are user-committed grammars and may contain errors (probably will in this case<sup>`[1]`</sup>!).

If you choose to place the `RangeError` there where it should be rewritte, like so:

```
function DoClear(num, arr, text){ 
  Contract.Requires<RangeError>(num > 0); 
  ...

  // method body
  ...

  Contract.Ensures<RangeError>(text.length === 0);

  return text; 
}
```

which would result in:

```
function DoClear(num, arr, text){ 
   if (!(num > 0)) throw RangeError; 
   ...

   // method body
   ...

   if (!(text.length === 0)) 
     throw RangeError 

   return text; 
}
```

then you need not parse the entire method body, and you might get away with a hack as I proposed.

Best of luck!

`[1]` the last time I checked these ECMA/JS script grammars, none of them handled regex literals, `/pattern/`, properly, making them in my opinion suspect.

Comment: i was able to work out a return mechanism.
i'm controlling scope with a stack and a list of contract actions, on every return i print out the contracts.
the only problem i'm having is that the parser throws errors everytime it finds anything like 're*', that's because i've define a  rule for 'return'.

Comment: @MateusBR, I assume your comment is a follow up question? If so, feel free to create a new question regarding this.